# Set default input values on jquery ui daterange picker inputs to be specific dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, daterangepicker

I'm using jquery ui daterange datepicker http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range my code is below it's pretty much the default initialization. I would like my "to" input field value to be todays date,and the "from" input field value to be 30 days prior. I haven't found anyway to set these input values dynamically, any help's appreciated

Thanks

```
<div id="date-wrapper">
<script>
$(function() {
    var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        dateFormat: "M d, yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
</script>
<label for="from"></label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from"/><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;">-</span>
<label for="to"></label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to initiate the two fields separately. You could save the settings to an object for reuse though.

The JavaScript would look something like:

```
var settings = {
    dateFormat: "M d, yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
            instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        $("#from, #to").not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
    }
};
$("#to").datepicker(settings);
$("#from").datepicker($.extend({}, settings, { defaultDate: '-30d'}));
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/xtATL/.

---

**Edit**:

You can make use of the utility function `$.datepicker.formatDate(format, date, settings)` to format a date to be displayed in the input:

```
$("#to").val(function() {
    return $.datepicker.formatDate('M d, yy', new Date(), settings);
});
$("#from").val(function() {
    var thirtyDaysAgo = new Date().getTime() - 30 * (1000*60*60*24);
    return $.datepicker.formatDate('M d, yy', new Date(thirtyDaysAgo), settings);
});
```

See the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/xtATL/4/.

Comment: Hi William, thanks for the reply and code. I see that the date is set in the popup datepicker to 30 days prior and today for the from and to inputs. But what I wanted was for when the page loads to set the input value such as <input type="text" value="Aug 12, 2011" name="from" id="from"><input type="text" value="Sep 11, 2011" name="to" id="to> so that when the page loads the inputs are not empty, any ideas how to do this? Thanks again

Comment: Thanks William, yes it is I changed the fiddle as much as I could and your edit above helped solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Either set the date in the input (using the correct date format) prior to initialising the datepicker, or use the setDate method if the datepicker after initialisation. E.g.

var d = new Date();
jQuery("#to).datepicker("setDate", d);